# Insert an array into MySQL using LabVIEW and Workbench

Tags: mysql, arrays, mysql-workbench, labview

I am running an experiment and want to log a double array of 500 values to a MySQL table using LabVIEW.  The amount of results will vary per test, and may be up to 2,000 but usually 500.

Firstly, I am instantiating a database.  I am thinking of setting the column to mediumtext, is that the best type?

Secondly, advice such as [here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/can-I-insert-a-column-of-array-into-mysql/m-p/3087240#M882580), suggests first converting all double arrays to comma separated strings.  Is that the best approach?

It all seems very contrived, is there a better way of storing arrays in MySQL?

Comment: If you store the entire array in a single column it will hard to query and manipulate the data.  A better option would be to store the array in multiple _records_, along with other metadata (e.g. a timestamp for when you collected the data, etc.).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not sure as I think creating a table with 1000 columns would be also difficult to search too.  Maybe you're right but it's not my call.  Arrays to columns.  Do you think the above is sensible?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped my initial comment, I meant to say _rows_.  Store your data row wise as this is the intention of the database.

Comment: I order to help you I think we need to know why you're storing this data in a database instead of just creating a folder of CSVs. E.g. I needed to store 1M DAQ waveforms in a DB and be able to query them and display them to a user. I needed a DB because the waveforms had metadata and I needed to maintain integrity between the raw signal data and the metadata.

Comment: If you will actually need to work with that data you will regret storing it as either a comma separated list or a json string.

Answer (score 3):

An array usually consists of values all of the same type. That fits perfectly to a database column, where all values have the same type as well. Hence, for e.g. an array of double, you could create a column that takes float values and insert each member of the array as individual row. 500 rows is nothing, you could insert millions that way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, each row would then have to include a timestamp, serial number, temperature value an possibly a sequence number if the timestamp granularity is not suffcient.  I'm currently opting for the medium text variable and storing the array a csv type string but would be great if there was something between the two options.

Comment: Give the JSON data type a try, which might be a perfect fit for such data.

Answer (score 0):

- below query works to insert array of string to the column in MYSql Workbench

```
insert into tableName (column1) values ('["Lorem Ipsum","Lorem Ipsum","Lorem Ipsum","Lorem Ipsum","Lorem Ipsum"]')
```